# Fix Error "0x8078015B" when doing an image backup from win 10 on samba share

Tags: windows, debian, backup, samba, windows-10

I'm trying setting up backups for my computer on a samba share and getting this error on windows 10: `Windows Backup encountered an error when accessing the remote shared folder. Please retry the operation after making sure that the remote shared folder is available and accessible. (0x8078015B)` 
Backup is working fine on Windows 7.

I've tried the following already:

- Cleaning the shared folder from older backups
- Checking the filesystem for errors with chekdsk /f /r -> there was nothing to repair
- Deaktivating antivirus
- Checking if windows services are set up and running
- Checking for accesebility
- Deactivating Wifi

Set up for samba is as follows:

- Debian server with an encrypted extarnal harddrive connected via USB and mounted through a device mapper-
- 1TB space for every user on a 10TB harddrive (windows 10 client has a 250GB Harddrive).

Samba configuration

```
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   log level = 1 auth:5 winbind:5
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = no
   ntlm auth = true
   map untrusted to domain = Yes
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   # path = /var/samba/backup_drive/users/%u
   path = %H
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
```

Links I have tried:

- [[FIX] Error 0x80070079: The Semaphore Timeout Period Has Expired](https://www.kapilarya.com/error-0x80070079-the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired-windows-10)
- [I get error code during backup: 0x8078015B](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/i-get-error-code-during-backup-0x8078015b/def4a56e-ee41-46e9-9965-1112c66cd64f)
- [How to fix Windows Backup Error Code 0x8078015B](https://superuser.com/questions/200356/how-to-fix-windows-backup-error-code-0x8078015b)